# Spring boot and Bean validation in different methods and the same class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I'm doing a rest webservice with spring boot and I would like to know if is possible do different validations with bean validation annotations by method with a POJO as param in the controller layer.

example:

POJO:

```
    Public class Person{
            @NotNull(forMethod="methodOne")
            private String firstName;
            @NotNull(forMehotd="methodTwo")
            private String lastName;
            private String age;

            //getter and setter
    }
```

Controller

```
    @RestController
    public class controller{

        @RequestMapping(....)
        public ResponseEntity methodOne(@Valid @RequestBody Person person){
            .....
        }

        @RequestMapping(....)
            public ResponseEntity methodTwo(@Valid @RequestBody Person person){
            ......
        }
    }
```

I know that is possible do it with separate parameters in the methods, but I have a POJO with so many attributes. is it possible do something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use `validation groups` in your bean validation annotations and use `@Validated` annotation instead of `@Valid` annotation. because `@Validated` annotation has a `value` properties that specifies a group for validation.

for example:

```
Public class Person{
        @NotNull(groups={MethodOne.class})
        private String firstName;
        @NotNull(groups={MethodTwo.class})
        private String lastName;
        private String age;

        //getter and setter
}
```

and

```
@RestController
public class controller{

    @RequestMapping(....)
    public ResponseEntity methodOne(@Validated(MethodOne.class) @RequestBody Person person){
        .....
    }

    @RequestMapping(....)
        public ResponseEntity methodTwo(@Validated(MethodTwo.class) @RequestBody Person person){
        ......
    }
}
```

by the way, don't forget that you should create `MethodOne` and `MethodTwo` interfaces to use them as your validation groups.

Comment: I think that solution is not so good for some controller with many methods, but for my case it worked. Thanks for you answer.

Comment: you are welcome and I think in that case, it's better to define different kinds of `DTO`s with their own validations for different controller methods instead of using the actual Entities.